# Getting call to Undefined Function mysqli_connect() but function still works

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

I'm getting the dreaded:

> Fatal Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

I've read the forums and understand this is typically fixed by turning on the MySQLi extension in php.ini.  I have done this.

My concern and my question is that the referenced function works fine.  I connect to the database and i'm able to run queries on the database.  But keeps throwing this error.

Is it possible that the program is looking at 2 different php.ini files?  When I run `phpinfo();` it shows the correct php.ini file.  If this is the culprit, how can I figure out where this other phantom php.ini file is?

I'm using phpdesigner8 to write and test my code. I have XAMPP and MySQL workbench that I also use on my testing machine.  Just curious if this will even matter to the end product.  Again everything works fine, even when I put it on my live server.  Just don't want this to get in the way on down the road, i'm only about 10% done with the coding and don't want to get 90% and this simple thing be the one thing that crashes the whole program.

Here is my connect file that I'm using:

```
$server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx";
$user = "xxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$database = "xxxxxxxx";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database);

if (!$conn) {
    die("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you restarted XAMPP after changing the config?

Comment: I have several times.  It's just troubling that everything seems to be working except for this one error, but it's not hindering the processing of forms and queries on the database

Comment: That is really odd. Maybe it'll work if you convert it to PDO.